# Mi boton enlazado a una funcion JQuery no responde

Tags: jquery, html5

El problema que tengo es que al pulsar el boton que tengo en el formulario de login debería ocultar el primer div(box-login) para a continuación mostrar el otro div(box-registro). Sin embargo al pulsar ignora la funcion que tiene el onClick, he probado a usar el depurador y si que entra en la funcion, sin embargo no hace lo que hay dentro. A continuación muestro el código. Un saludo.

```
<div class="box-login">
<form class="login" action="Login.php" method="post">
    <img id="logo" src="imagenes/logo.jpg" alt="logo">
    <h1>Iniciar Sesión</h1>
    <input type="text" name="user" placeholder="DNI">
    <input type="password" name="pass" placeholder="Contraseña">
    <?php
        if(isset($_GET["fail_pass"]) && $_GET["fail_pass"]=='true'){
            echo'<div style="color:red">Contraseña incorrecta</div>';
        }
    ?>
    <input type="submit" name="Enviar" value="Login">
    <button  class="other" >He olvidado la contraseña</button><br>
    <button class="other" onclick="CambiaPagina()">¿No tienes cuenta? Regístrate</button>
</form>
</div>
    <div class="box-registro">
<form class="sign_in" action="Registro.php" method="post">
    <img id="logo" src="imagenes/logo.jpg" alt="logo">
    <h1>Registro</h1>
    <!--Usuario-->
    <div class="campo">
    <label for="user">DNI</label>
    <input type="text" name="user" placeholder="DNI">
    </div>
    <!--Contraseña + comprobador -->
    <div class="campo">
    <label for="pass">Contraseña</label>
    <input type="password" name="pass" placeholder="Contraseña">
    <label for="pass2">Vuelva a introducir la contraseña</label>
    <input type="password" name="pass" placeholder="Contraseña">
    </div>
    <!-- Nombre y Apellidos -->
    <div class="campo">
    <label for="nombre">Nombre y apellido</label>
    <input type="text" name="nombre" placeholder="Raul Perez Martin">
    </div>
    <!--Correo electronico + comprobador-->
    <div class="campo">
    <label for="correo"> Correo electronico</label>
    <input type="text" name="correo" placeholder="emailDeEjemplo@gmail.com">
    </div>

    <!--Telefono + comprobador-->
    <div class="campo">
    <label for="tlfn">Telefono</label>
    <input type="text" name="Telefono" placeholder="Telefono">
    </div>
    <input type="submit" name="Enviar" value="Login">
    <a >Ya tengo una cuenta</a>
</form>
</div>
<script>
    $(".box-registro").hide();
    function CambiaPagina(){
        $(".box-login").hide(1000);
        $(".box-registro").show(1000);
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El `onclick` funciona pero como tienes el `button` dentro de un form pues por defecto el comportamiento de un botón dentro de un form es hacer el submit de dicho form al `action` establecido.

Para evitar dicho comportamiento puedes añadir el atributo `type` al botón.

```
 <button class="other" type="button" onclick="CambiaPagina()">¿No tienes cuenta? Regístrate</button>
```